# Possible approaches to create dependency among jobs in Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have several jobs in spring batch.

The first job is kind of a validation job which runs some database queries and knows that the further jobs should run or not.

But how to pass this knowledge across to remaining jobs that they should run or abend ?

What could be the best approach in this case ?

One approach I can think of is to create a flag file (unix touch command) which will indicate other jobs to run. The final job will delete the file in the final step for the next days run.

Is this correct approach ? If yes, how to run the touch command from inside the tasklet ?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: there exists specific software for this requirement, e.g. uc4, but  for a simple solution, i would use a shell script which acts as the "job controller"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is very easy: read [§5.3.2.1. Batch Status vs. Exit Status](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#batchStatusVsExitStatus):

```
<step id="step1">
    <end on="FAILED" />
    <next on="COMPLETED WITH SKIPS" to="fallbackStep" />
    <next on="*" to="step2" />
</step>
<step id="step2" />
<step id="fallbackStep" />
```

Comment: Probably you did not read my question... I know that dependency between steps is possible... But I do not want that.. I want dependency between the jobs...

Comment: @NikunjChauhan: Perhaps you need to be more exact with your question. You ask "... that they should run or abend". That is exactly what is achieved using flows. If you need to pass some information between jobs, then use `ExecutionContext`.